# camel REST DSL streaming file

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, zip, streaming

We are trying to retrieve data from a Database and stream the result back to the REST client in a ZipOutputStream. The code is implemented in Camel

The data is quite large. Therefore loading all of it at once would cause memory problems.
We get the data in the sql camel component. Then split the result. Each splitted exchange creates a File stream (InputStream). All files should get zipped into 1 file and returned. How is this possible with Camel?

```
rest("/api/v1/request/{Id}/data")
            .get().outType(StreamingOutput.class)
                .route().routeId("getDataRoute")
                    .to("sql:SELECT * FROM Data WHERE ID_ID=:#id?outputType=StreamList")
                    .split(body()).parallelProcessing().stopOnException()
                    .bean(new FileStreamTranslator)
    //Generate a filestream per split. Zip the files and return the ZipStream. how can this be achieved?
```

Comment: I guess we could use an aggregator and a JdbcAggregationRepository. But would that load the whole aggregate into memory upon retrieval

Comment: Solved this by creating a temp file and a pollenrich to stream it out with RestDSL

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?